# HTML5 drag and drop - "dragend" not fired when source element is moved or removed by Angular

Tags: angularjs, html, drag-and-drop, angulardraganddroplists

I'm using Google's [Angular Drag and Drop Lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists), but I think the problem is with the underlying HTML5 drag and drop not working with Angular ( v1.6.1 ).

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#dragend) ( the note at the bottom, under "Finishing a Drag" ):

> "dragend" is not dispatched if the source node is moved or removed during the drag (e.g. on "drop" or "dragover").  [bug 460801](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=460801)

I'm altering the Angular model in the "dragover" event to display feedback during the drag operation. I **think** Angular is moving or removing ( and recreating ) my source element and this is what is stopping "dragend" from firing.

This means I have no way of knowning when the drag operation is finished when unsuccessful ( when successful the "drop" event is fired on the target element )

Any ideas please?

Comment: Example that will demonstrate problem will be very helpfull. (Why you think angular removes node? I know that angular is bad guy, but usually it does what you code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question for posterity!

I solved the issue my making sure the Angular digest loop did not run during the drag and drop operation.

This seems to support my theory about the source element being removed and recreated by Angular preventing the dragend event from firing.

I had to fall back to JQuery to provide visual feedback during the drag and drop.

HTH